# Most expensive / valuable role-playing game

Tags: collector-value

What are the most expensive role-playing games (or individual supplements)?

The question refers to the cost of an individual game or other product - not to the potentially continuous expense of having to purchase new supplements / miniatures etc.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the usefulness/relevance of this question? It seems more related to collectibles or something. Just asking.

Comment: While not the greatest question in the world, I don't see anything wrong with asking about collecting RPGs. It going to come up on how to find older material.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Dungeons & Dragons, an original "woodgrain" boxed set is by far the most collectible/valuable item.  Only 1000 copies were printed back in 1974 (assembled on Gary Gygax's kitchen table by family and friends) and a near mint copy could bring as much as $5000 at auction.

Other expensive/collectible D&D items include tournament versions of Ghost Tower of Inverness, Lost Tamoachan, and Lost Caverns of Tsojconth; a 1st print of Palace of the Vampire Queen (first offical D&D module ever published), Daystar West versions of Rahasia and Pharaoh, ST1 Up the Garden Path (UK module only available at a special con in 1986), Original 1st Edition Chainmail, and a "alpha print" of the 1st edition Dungeon Masters Guide (with Monster Manual pages bound in places).  Any of these in nice shape go for over $1000 or more at auction....

Comment: FYI, in Sept of 2010 a beautiful woodgrain 1st print set, with a handwritten letter from Gary Gygax himself included, was sold on Ebay for $5600!

Answer (score 6):

Only a few copies of the **Dune** RPG were ever printed by Last Unicorn Games. Copies regularly fetch several hundred dollars at auction sites.

Comment: 900 copies exactly, it was only the Core Book. Just bought it from abebooks.com it is really a magnificent book and universe.

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about old stuff as well, an original White Box edition D&D set is very pricey. There are reports of them selling at auction for 1,000s.

Comment: I still have the old D&D Red Dragon Box... It's a shame it is well used.

Answer (score 5):

Both Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay (3rd edition) and Dungeons & Dragons 4th edition are the priciests RPGs to get today both require $100+ to get the complete core game.

The original Dungeons & Dragon woodgrain set is most expensive collectors item.

A notable recent collector game is the Dune Roleplaying game which can sell for $100+.

Comment: 4th edition is changing soon (with the release of the Essentials line).

Answer (score 5):

The Nobilis Great White Book routinely went for over $100 when a copy would show up on Ebay.  Now that a 3rd edition of the game is in the works though, I don't know if it will continue to command those kind of prices.

Answer (score 4):

The signed, numbered, limited edition of A Game of Thrones from the now-defunct Guardians of Order went for over $100 when it was released. A very few were recently discovered by GRRM in his garage and sold for who knows how much. This is a beautiful book full of information about Westeros. I have one and consider myself lucky. I have the map that was available from GoO at the time framed on the wall near my dining room table.

The new Song of Ice and Fire RPG from Green Ronin is a far superior **game**, however.

I'd bet that the book goes for well over $200 today if you can find someone willing to part with a pristine copy. Mine has never been read cover-to-cover. I printed a b&w copy from the PDF that I got with the game and used that as a "table copy" to play when I ran the game.

Answer (score 0):

1st edition battle system with the first bloodstone module is expensive.
Leather edition of Deadlands
TSR empire of the petal throne
Guardians of orders Tekumel
Legit first printings of the 1st edition AD&D books.